# Measure Symfony's httpClient and Doctrine queries execution time and create Prometheus metrics

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, prometheus, symfony-http-client

there are actually two separate questions under this title

- I am trying to figure out how to measure the requests duration made to external services in Symfony application via the httpClient and same for Doctrine queries.
  For Doctrine queries I am considering option to create Lifecycle Event Listener and measure pre post timestamps of request but I think they are only for create/update/delete operations but not for get. Also performance is concern with this approach.
- Also I am still getting familiar with Prometheus but I would like to post those values as metrics to Prometheus (I would figure out this eventually after I get the data).
  I have `promphp/prometheus_client_php` installed and basic metrics are running fine.

Would be grateful if someone faced similar case to share some opinion.

Comment: To measure performance in symfony and execution time in http and doctrine query, there is a component in symfony, known as stopwatch: composer require symfony/stopwatch
See website documentation on how to use it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment - stopwatch is just a component that parses the timestamps for us.
I am more curious of a general way to plug in and measure httpClient and doctrine requests duration.